# Removing an unknown linux printer

Tags: linux, printing, network-printer, cups

Linux printing appeared to be working fine up until yesterday. Today typing lpq gives the following:

> lpq
>   Printer 'sdst@other.domain' - cannot open connection - Connection timed out
>   Make sure LPD server is running on the server

The /etc/cups/printers.conf file is properly set, the printers appear in localhost:631 and they are printing test pages. However, all command line print commands seem to be trying to print to sdst@other.domain

I don't know why printers.conf is being ignored and why and how sdst@other.domain was added. Seems like it might have been auto-discovered?

#

edit: sdst@other.domain was mentioned in /usr/local/etc/lpd.conf
I'm not sure why lpd.conf is being used instead of /etc/cups/printers.conf

Any suggestions or any idea how cups can be used instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out someone had copied old versions of

lp, lpq, lpstat to /usr/local/bin and that was causing the wrong bins to launch.

One fix was

mv /usr/local/bin/lp /usr/local/bin/old_lp
mv /usr/local/bin/lpq /usr/local/bin/old_lpq
mv /usr/local/bin/lpstat /usr/local/bin/old_lpstat
mv /usr/local/bin/lpr /usr/local/bin/old_lpr
mv /usr/local/bin/lprm /usr/local/bin/old_lprm
mv /usr/local/bin/lprsetup.sh /usr/local/bin/old_lprsetup.sh

The printing has returned to normal now.

the sdst@other.domain was in /usr/local/etc/ldp.conf